# How to use window.location.href in Electron?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have a react app which I've converted to Electron app also.
In the app after I **logout** I'm redirecting the user back to **login** screen using

```js
window.location.href="/login"
```

it is working perfectly in React build. But in Electron build it is not redirecting to the login route rather the app crashes. In the network tab there is an API call made to `C:///login` in Windows. So I am confused on how to use the same in React and Electron without breaking UI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the path you are giving in your redirection : `"/login"`

The `/` at the start means that you are going back to the root directory, and in the case of Electron, the root directory is actually the root directory of your computer. That's why it then makes an API call all the way up to `C:///login`.

To avoid that, simply remove the leading `/` and use a **relative path** from your logout page to your login page. See for example : https://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/relative_paths/relative_paths.htm